# undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

def creation

```
(1..params[:book_detail][:no_of_copies].to_i).each do |i|

  logger.info "nnnnnnnnnnn#{i}"
  @book_details= BookDetail.new(params[:book_detail])
  @book_details.save
end
```

And the Error is 
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
app/controllers/book_details_controller.rb:16:in`creation'

Is anybody can tell what is the problem?

Comment: can u just print the params[:book_detail] inside creation?

Comment: The error message is clear -- Either `params` or `params[:book_detail]` is `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

Error you are getting is because `params[:book_detail]` is `nil` and you are calling `[:no_of_copies]` on it i.e. nil.So it is giving following error

```
 undefined method []' for nil:NilClass
```

So you need to check first if `params[:book_detail]` is present or not like following

```
(1..params[:book_detail][:no_of_copies].to_i).each do |i|    
  logger.info "nnnnnnnnnnn#{i}"
  @book_details= BookDetail.new(params[:book_detail])
  @book_details.save
end if params[:book_detail] && params[:book_detail][:no_of_copies]
```

Comment: as said by @Dogbert in the comments, `params` could be nil as well

Comment: @Baboon I don't think so. Unless you explicitly have set params to nil, in controller it would always contain some values

Answer (score 0):

In addition is Salil's answer, you can use `fetch`

```
params.fetch(:book_detail, {})[:no_of_copies]
```

which will return `nil` if `params[:book_detail]` is `nil`.  `(1..0).to_a` returns an empty array so you can rewrite your code using the following

```
copies = (params.fetch(:book_detail, {})[:no_of_copies] || 0).to_i

(1..copies).each do |i|    
  logger.info "nnnnnnnnnnn#{i}"
  @book_details= BookDetail.new(params[:book_detail])
  @book_details.save
end
```